# "LEVIN_PACKET partial msg received" while syncing

Tags: monerod, synchronization

Should I pay attention to the set_level 2 print outs?

Sometimes I get a lot of these:

"LEVIN_PACKET partial msg received len=1400"

(The 1400 varies)

Anyone know what that means?
Or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I pay attention to the set_level 2 print outs?

Not unless you're debugging / developing.

> Anyone know what that means?

It means exactly what it says. And it's a debug message.

> Or it doesn't matter?

It doesn't matter at all to someone not developing or debugging, just like the vast majority of other debug messages.